# How to read keys that user presses without specifying the exact key?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically what I need is an idea how to shorten my code.

So what I have now is an IF series to get the keys that user presses:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            AddToBuffer("I");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.N))
        {
            AddToBuffer("N");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            AddToBuffer("F");
        }
```

It works perfectly well, but what I want is to shorten it so it would be possible to save to buffer any key (better, as a string)

So that I would no more have to specify what key was pressed.

(Maybe something like TryParse etc.)

Comment: Does Input.inputString cover what you're looking for? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-inputString.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[InputString](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-inputString.html) contains a string all keys pressed down on the current frame. It is recommended to break the string down into characters as shown in the input string example in Unity documentation, as inputString can contain backspace '\b' and enter '\n' characters.

An example of listening for cheatcodes might look like this:

```
string cheatCode = "money";
int cheatIndex = 0;
void Update()
{
    if(Input.anyKeyDown)
    {
        foreach (char c in Input.inputString)
        {
            if(c == cheatCode[cheatIndex])
            {
                //the next character was entered correctly
                Debug.Log("The next character {0} was entered correctly", c);
                //On the next key down, check the next character
                cheatIndex++;
            } else
            {
                //The character was not correctly entered, reset the cheat index back to the start of the code
                Debug.Log("Cheat code invalid. {0} was not the next character", c);
                cheatIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        if(cheatIndex == cheatCode.Length)
        {
            Debug.Log("Cheat code was successfully entered")
        }
    }
}
```

I have not written this in Unity and tested it, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Let me check how it works...

Comment: If you wanted to work with a list of cheatcodes, you'll need to iterate through that list and check each one as you go. I assume you can expand this code to fit that need if you want.

Comment: Well, I that's solves my problem, in addition to working with a list of cheat codes it's also reasonable to limit the time the user has to enter a cheat code. So I used some part of your code and integrated it with mine (specifically 
        if (Input.anyKeyDown)
        {
            foreach (char c in Input.inputString)
            {
                AddToBuffer(c.ToString());
            }
        }
)

Answer (score 3):

You can use "any key": https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-anyKey.html

```
if (Input.anyKey)
{
    Debug.Log("A key or mouse click has been detected");
    // get the pressed key:
    String keycode = Event.current.keyCode.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I think he needs to get the actual keys that were pressed, not only if a key was pressed.

Comment: right. Added code to get the pressed key.

Comment: yes, checking how it works now...

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, for some reason, a null reference exception occurs

Comment: Maybe if I specify what exactly I'm trying to do, it will be easier to get. 
I am implementing some cheat codes, so I somehow need to read keys that are in the code and simultaneously keep on tracking other keys that are useful for moving player and so on

Comment: null reference probably because "Event.current" doesnt exist. I think this code only works on OnGui and similar, where Events happen.

Comment: Yep, that's correct, I've just found it out. But no matter, they guy above helped me to solve the problem with Input.inputString. Thanks for your help too!