# KeyCode but I want the input change with an array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm a beginner, so I don't know how to do this

I want to user type a letter in the dialogue, then after the user inputs the letter, it moves to the next array, then so on, I thought it gonna be work, but well

```
private string[] type;
private string dialogue;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    dialogue = "ThisIsATest";
    type = new string[dialogue.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < dialogue.Length; i++)
    {
        type[i] = System.Convert.ToString(dialogue[i]);
        
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.type[i])) 
    {
        Debug.Log("It works!");
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you actually want to happen after the user input? Do you update a UI element or something? If you've tried something show that code too.

Comment: Does this answer your questions? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72088963/11947519